# Rules triggering rules - how to enforce or disable it

Tags: 7, rules

There are many situations in which a rule could trigger another rule.  For example, If I have a rule that reacts to a Node being created, I can trigger that rule with another rule that created a node.  The same should hold true for flagging nodes, but I have seen cases in which it does not.  I have written 'single flag enforcement' rules that are triggered by a node being flagged, which un-flag all nodes flagged by that user, then re-flag only the triggering node.  This rule should trigger itself over and over infinitely, but it does not.   How does Drupal's Rules handle these situation?  Is there a way to force rules to allow or disallow this form of cascading rule triggering (and potentially cause/prevent an infinite loop?)

Answer (score 1):

It will not trigger recursively, Rules has inbuilt mechanism to prevent this. if you check the function [rules_element_invoke_component](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!modules!rules_core.eval.inc/function/rules_element_invoke_component/7) you can see this.

```
function rules_element_invoke_component($arguments, RulesPlugin $element) {
  ....
  // Handle recursion prevention.
  if ($state->isBlocked($component)) {
     return rules_log('Not evaluating @plugin %label to prevent recursion.',  $replacements, RulesLog::INFO, $component);
  }
  $state->block($component);
  ....
}
```

Comment: Is that to say that a rule will not trigger itself, but it can trigger a different rule if the actions match triggers?

Comment: Yes, if you check the [rules.state.inc](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!includes!rules.state.inc/7) file you can see `static protected $blocked = array();` where they are storing the rule id.

Comment: It looks like a rule can be called multiple times on a single page load, but not as a 'child process' of the same rule.

Comment: I don't think so, can you explain a scenario.

Comment: As Once a rule is called, it is added to the blocked array, which prevents it from being called later.  However, a rule can be called several times (by views bulk operations) on a page load, so it looks like the blocked array is reset at some point.

Comment: Yeah, as you said a rule cannot be called as a child process. But as per VBO, assume that we have a rule that triggers when a user is updated and we are performing bulk user update. Even though this is a bulk operation for us internally it is only loop. And after each updation if a rule is not triggering any other rule then it will unblock `$state->unblock($component);`, so it will trigger for the next update also.